# What the .out files in the hadoop logs folder? Is it safe to delete them?

Tags: hadoop, log4j

I manage a small fully distributed hadoop cluster and I was doing my routine cleanup of logs and inspection. I see a bunch of files with the `.out` extension in the {HADOOP_HOME}/logs path that I configured. There are several such as:

```
hadoop-<my-system-name>-namenode-<my-system-name>.out
hadoop-<my-system-name>-namenode-<my-system-name>.out.1
hadoop-<my-system-name>-namenode-<my-system-name>.out.2
hadoop-<my-system-name>-datanode-<my-system-name>.out
hadoop-<my-system-name>-historyserver-<my-system-name>.out
hadoop-<my-system-name>-historyserver-<my-system-name>.out.2
hadoop-<my-system-name>-historyserver-<my-system-name>.out.3
hadoop-<my-system-name>-resourcemanager-<my-system-name>.out
hadoop-<my-system-name>-resourcemanager-<my-system-name>.out.1
hadoop-<my-system-name>-secondarynamenode-<my-system-name>.out
hadoop-<my-system-name>-secondarynamenode-<my-system-name>.out.1
hadoop-<my-system-name>-secondarynamenode-<my-system-name>.out.2
```

etc. etc. etc.

When I look at one of them with an editor, such as the `hadoop-<my-system-name>-namenode-<my-system-name>.out.1` file, I get:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 514997
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 16384
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 8092
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

What are these files? Do they serve a purpose to keep or can they be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like all good applications, logs serve a great purpose - finding out what is happening with your service. You *should **probably*** be putting the logs into something like Elasticsearch/Solr/Graylog/etc to search/alert on them

Anything that ends in a number can be safely deleted.

They are managed by the `log4j.properties` RollingFileAppender that is started with Hadoop.

Comment: I don't really need put the logs anywhere as of now because it would be overkill for this cluster that is built for a test sandbox of sorts. It wouldn't even matter if the data on HDFS was wiped because it isn't critical as such. Thank you for your answer.